# ad_gpo_map_interactive disappeared from sssd?

Tags: networking, login, samba, security

A corporate windows active directory :-( is responsible of user credentials on an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. It's using samba and sssd on the Linux side.

I had to add ad_gpo_map_interactive = +cron in the sssd.conf in order to allow cron for those users.

Since an apt upgrade which happened 4 weeks ago, the active directory credentials does not works anymore.

I've found today that the ad_gpo_map_interactive is not recognised anymore. I have removed that line and it works like a charm... Also, cron works now without that directive.

But, well, I don't understandt what happened. And since it has to deal with security ... I'm not confident.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot.
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No activity here, so maybe the wrong stack exchange site.

Closing, and moved to server fault: https://serverfault.com/questions/971402/ad-gpo-map-interactive-disappeared-from-sssd